# sqlTables in R from RODBC package not getting correct set of tables

Tags: r, rodbc

I have 2 schemas in the mysql database. One is labeled p73, the other is labeled p75. I am trying to get the set of tables associated with p75 however, when i call **tables <- sqlTables (channel, schema - "p75")** I still get the set of tables associated with p73.

How do I solve this problem?
Here is the code from my script

```
library(RODBC)
print("enter DSN name")
dsn <- readline()
print("enter user name")
user <- readline()
print("enter password")
pw<- readline()

channel<- odbcConnect(dsn, user, pw)
print("Please enter project name (ex: p73)")
pj <- readline()
tables <- sqlTables (channel, schema - pj)
```

Comment: SO is full of nice and good people, but, as far as I know, no one is a clairvoyant. You should supply more information if you want some help. What's your db? How did you create your channel object? My guess is that it is still pointing to the p73 schema for some reason.

Comment: good point. hopefully the posted code is enough to help.

Comment: Is it  a minus sign instead of `=`? It should be `schema=pj`. However, you didn't provide much information. What kind of database are you trying to connect? How is your dsn defined?